# На сайте не отображается div( а в нем кнопка )

Tags: html

Очень странно. Кнопка не отображается, и не одна. Помогите исправить.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% block content %}
<form action="" method = 'POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-md-6 mt-4">
            <label for="validationCustom04" class="form-label">Имя задачи:</label>
            {% render_field form.name class="form-control" rows="3" cols="5" %}
        </div>
    </div>

    
    <div class="row align-items-center" name="Описание">
        <div class="col-md-6 mt-4">
            <label for="validationCustom04" class="form-label">Описание:</label>
            {% render_field form.description class="form-control" %}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="validationCustom04" class="form-label">Категории</label>
        <select class="form-select" id="validationCustom04" name="category_select" required>
            <option selected disabled value="">Выберите категорию</option>
            {% for category in categories %}
            <option class="" value="{{category.name}}" name="{{category.name}}">{{category.name}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
#Первая кнопка, которая не отображается
    <div class="col-5 mt-2">
        {% if todo.completed == False %}
            <button class="btn btn-danger" id="click">{{todo.completed}}</button>
            <div id="block"></div>
        {% else %}
            <button class="btn btn-success" id="click">{{todo.completed}}</button>
            <div id="block"></div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
#Вторая кнопка, которая не отображается
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col mt-4">
            <input type="submit" value="Сохранить" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>
    </div>
    
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Все.. Я понял. Вот эта штука мешала `<div class="invalid-feedback">`
Теперь все норм

Comment: Просто теги были не закрыты. 2 шт